# Android Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error

Tags: android, dalvik

I am getting the following error- do not know why? I will be grateful if anybody can solve this problem. thanks

```
[2014-03-12 11:09:36 - mediasenseapp] Dx 
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
[2014-03-12 11:09:36 - mediasenseapp] Dx local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type java.lang.Object[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.

[2014-03-12 11:09:36 - mediasenseapp] Dx ...at bytecode offset 000000c7
locals[0000]: Lch/qos/logback/classic/gaffer/ComponentDelegate;
locals[0001]: [Ljava/lang/Object;
locals[0002]: [Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
locals[0003]: Ljava/lang/String;
locals[0004]: Ljava/lang/Class;
locals[0005]: Lgroovy/lang/Closure;
locals[0006]: <invalid>
stack[top0]: Ljava/lang/Object;
...while working on block 00c6
...while working on method analyzeArgs:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
...while processing analyzeArgs ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
...while processing ch/qos/logback/classic/gaffer/ComponentDelegate.class

[2014-03-12 11:09:36 - mediasenseapp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-03-12 11:09:36 - mediasenseapp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: how u got this like what u did in code i.e u got this

Answer (score 0):

I do *NOT* meat this error before. But reading your error log: `Dx local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type java.lang.Object[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.`, I think the problem is your using Libraries. In the following log, I suppose you may use *groovy* to develop your Android code. And then using the **DX** to convert your codes.

As I knew, the Android support *java 6* version, but it does NOT mean it can support groovy or higher version of java.

If you can give more information, I may rebuild your demo. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :)
that error is gone now somehow! dont ask me- how!! anyway, i am getting new errors like it says certain class not found which is called by another class. but all these classes exist in the .jar files. dont know. i have little android knowledge but same thing worked in java. i just wanted an android version of what i did in java.

Comment: @suzon_ I suggest you to see this project: http://code.google.com/p/discobot/. Good luck :-)